# Compare two different dataframes and add new values to a column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 DataFrames, where a column of df1 must be compared to another column, in df2, that have different dimensions, and if true, modify de df1[3].

```
if df1.loc[df1[1]] == df2.loc[df2[3]]:  
    df1[3] = 4
```

df1:

| 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| yy | 123 | x |  |
| xx | 445 | r |  |
| za | 336 | f |  |
| gs | 775 | e |  |
| fr | 447 | w |  |

df2:

| 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| T | 0 | x | 336 |
| S | 4 | r | 447 |
| R | 3 | f | 445 |

Expected result should be:

df1:

| 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| yy | 123 | x |  |
| xx | 445 | r | 4 |
| za | 336 | f | 4 |
| gs | 775 | e |  |
| fr | 447 | w | 4 |

```
 KeyError:None of [Index ... type='object', length=...)] are in the [index]"
```

Can someone help me with this? I know that probably is a simple thing, but i've tried a lot of ways and none of works.

Comment: `df1.loc[df1[1].isin(df2[3]), 3] = 4`.

Comment: You could also do a join and do an apply on the column?

Answer (score 0):

Use [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with [`isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html):

```
df1.loc[df1[1].isin(df2[3]), 3] = 4
```

output:

```
    0    1  2    3
0  yy  123  x  NaN
1  xx  445  r  4.0
2  za  336  f  4.0
3  gs  775  e  NaN
4  fr  447  w  4.0
```